# Do HLSL intrinsic functions support half type?

Tags: shader, hlsl

I'v been looking into glslang recently, and I noticed that almost all HLSL intrinsic functions don't support half-type directly. For example, there are `float max(float, float)`, `int max(int, int)` but no `half max(half, half)`. The Microsoft document also indicates that `float` and `int` component type are supported, they don't mension `half`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-max

But in shader, if you write `half res = max(1.0h, 2.0h)`, the shader compiles with no error. So does this `max` actually promote the two half parameters to float, get a float result and implicitly cast the result to half?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`half` is mapped to `float` on current HLSL, so your code actually calculates values using floats. [More info here](https://therealmjp.github.io/posts/shader-fp16/):

> But then the D3D10 era came along with its unified shader cores, and suddenly fp16 math was no more. None of the desktop hardware supported it anymore, and so HLSL went ahead and mapped the half type to float and called it day.

If you want to use real 16-bit values, you could try using `min16float` instead of `half`.

Comment: Worth adding this later quote "As of Nvidia's new Turing architecture (AKA the RTX 2000 series), AMD's Vega (AKA gfx900, AKA GCN 5) series1 and Intel's Gen8 architecture (used in Broadwell) fp16 is now back in the desktop world."

Also this Official Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-scalar